# Use SVGR and Material UI together

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui, svg-rect

i'm trying to use SVGR to convert my svg into react components and i need to use `<SvgIcon />` of Material UI and pass the converted component as a prop to it.
nothing wrong with this yet.

but,
SVGR saves these component in a folder called svgCom for example and inside of this folder there is `index.js` plus converted svg components.

i need to wrapp all these components inside of `<SvgIcon>` so i don't have to wrap this icon with `<SvgIcon/>` again for each use case;
so far i try to add this component in `template.js` of SVGR but it throw me an error when try to parse .

is this the best way of doing such thing or there is better way ?
if it is what's wrong with my template.js ?

here is my templete.js :

```
function template(
  { template },
  opts,
  { imports, componentName, props, jsx, exports },
) {
  return template.ast`
    ${imports}
     import { SvgIcon } from "@material-ui/core";
     ///////////////////////////////////// error here
    const ${componentName} = (${props}) => <SvgIcon component={${jsx}} />
    ${exports}
  `
}
module.exports = template
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and after some research I came to the following solution:

```
const {
  identifier,
  jsxClosingElement,
  jsxElement,
  jsxIdentifier,
  jsxOpeningElement,
  jsxSpreadAttribute,
} = require('@babel/types')

const iconTemplate = ({ template }, _, { componentName, jsx, exports }) => {
  const wrappedJsx = jsxElement(
    jsxOpeningElement(jsxIdentifier('SvgIcon'), [jsxSpreadAttribute(identifier('props'))]),
    jsxClosingElement(jsxIdentifier('SvgIcon')),
    [jsx],
    false
  )

  return template.ast`
    import React from 'react'
    import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon'

    const ${componentName} = (props) => ${wrappedJsx}
    ${exports}
  `
}

module.exports = iconTemplate
```

If you don't want `{...props}` on the `<svg>` tag, you have to disable the `expandProps` option

Comment: another option is use this CLI command in `package.json` file in script section.

`{"svg": "svgr -d src/@shared/icons --replace-attr-values '#343C49=currentColor, #343c49=currentColor' --ignore-existing public/svgIcons"}`
basically it compiles public/svgicon into @shared/icons and wrapped them in react component.

with this command you tell the Svgr change `[#hexColor]` to the `currentColor`  hen in css you can use color property to change the color of Svg.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Looked everywhere to figure out how to wrap into SvgIcon, this helped me do it.